# How to convert from std::shared_ptr to std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, memory-management, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

So i'm trying to build a template class for binary trees.
I have a special way that i want to use to initialize the tree (which you can see in `main()`).

The constructor works with `shared_ptr` just fine, but i want to move it to more lightweight `unique_ptr`, but i somehow get error-messages all over the place. Can someone explain how to get rid of the shared_ptrs?
Here is the working version with shared_ptr:

```
#include <optional>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template <class C>
class node{
private:
    C label;
    std::shared_ptr<node<C>> left;
    std::shared_ptr<node<C>> right;
public:
    node(const C& name,
            const std::optional<node<C>>& leftChild = {},
            const std::optional<node<C>>& rightChild = {}) : 
        label(name), 
        left(leftChild ? std::make_shared<node<C>>(*leftChild) : nullptr), 
        right(rightChild ? std::make_shared<node<C>>(*rightChild) : nullptr) {}
};

int main(){
    using sNode = node<std::string>;
    auto root = std::make_unique<sNode>("root", sNode("left", sNode("left.left")), sNode("right"));
}
```

I tried to just use unique instead of shared like that:

```
template <class C>
class node{
private:
    C label;
    std::unique_ptr<node<C>> left;
    std::unique_ptr<node<C>> right;
public:
    node(const C& name,
            const std::optional<node<C>>& leftChild = {},
            const std::optional<node<C>>& rightChild = {}) : 
        label(name), 
        left(leftChild ? std::make_unique<node<C>>(*leftChild) : nullptr), 
        right(rightChild ? std::make_unique<node<C>>(*rightChild) : nullptr) {}
};
```

But following compile-errors come up:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from binaryTree.hpp:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h: In instantiation of ‘typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object std::make_unique(_Args&& ...) [with _Tp = node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Args = {const node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&}; typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, std::default_delete<node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >]’:
binaryTree.hpp:15:51:   required from ‘node<C>::node(const C&, const std::optional<node<C> >&, const std::optional<node<C> >&) [with C = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
main.cpp:7:80:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:825:30: error: use of deleted function ‘node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::node(const node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’
     { return unique_ptr<_Tp>(new _Tp(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)); }
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
binaryTree.hpp:5:7: note: ‘node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::node(const node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class node{
       ^~~~
binaryTree.hpp:5:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Dp = std::default_delete<node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from binaryTree.hpp:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
binaryTree.hpp:5:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Dp = std::default_delete<node<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >]’
 class node{
       ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from binaryTree.hpp:2,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess it has to do with the deleted assignement-operator for `unique_ptr`, and i have to use `std::move()` sonmewhere, but i cant figure out where.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: But `shared_ptr` is as "light" as possible; why do you feel you need smthg lighter?

Comment: Because when i'm thinking about it, it doesn't seem like i need "shared" ownership. In my mind every node of a tree has exactly ONE parent, so ```unique_ptr``` seems like the better choice in terms of logical reasons -**Edit**: i feel like the ref count of ```shared_ptr``` is an unnecessary burden.

Comment: Indeed. Compared to unique "smart ptr", the shared ones provide at least one additional degree of freedom. It's a good practice to prefer tools with the least degrees of freedom covering your needs: a unique ptr provides a guarantee that there won't be another owner sharing the resource.

Comment: Basically you need to write some code to copy `unique_ptr` but then you are back to square one; that put together will be very likely inferior to `std::share_ptr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but i somehow get error-messages all over the place. Can someone explain how to get rid of the shared_ptrs?

`unique_ptr` is non-copyable, only movable. This means that as soon as you put in your class a `unique_ptr` member, `node` cannot be copied anymore: the implicit copy assignment and constructor that the compiler was generating for you won't be there anymore.

So you have to decide how you want your class to behave.

- If you want your `node`s to be copyable, you will have to implement the copy ops yourself (you will have to deep clone the tree). This will give you value semantics.
- Otherwise, if you don't want `node` to be copyable, you will still need to perform a deep clone of the `node` objects in the constructor. The reason is that since you are passing `const` references, you cannot take ownership of their memory (and you wanted them `const` since you likely wanted to be able to pass temporaries).
- Or you can change your interface to avoid taking references. Instead, take sink parameters (i.e. by value) and move them inside your constructor. (@rafix07 wrote this in an answer but it is now deleted). You can even do it for the `name` parameter:

  ```
  node(C name,
          std::optional<node<C>> leftChild = {},
          std::optional<node<C>> rightChild = {}) : 
      label(std::move(name)), 
      left(leftChild ? std::make_unique<node<C>>( std::move(*leftChild) ) : nullptr), 
      right(rightChild ? std::make_unique<node<C>>( std::move(*rightChild) ) : nullptr) {}
  ```

Comment: `std::optional<node<C>>` is how I might do it in some scenarios, but word of caution if I may. `std::optional` requires types that are "Trivially Destructible", thus imposing that requirement on both `C` and `node<C>`. But I see nothing wrong with `shared_ptr<T>` it is light and it is fast.

Comment: @ChefGladiator Note that `shared_ptr` is not light/fast compared to `unique_ptr`. There are three overheads: the size (2x), the ref-counting and the atomics.

Comment: @ChefGladiator If you think you can write a "*quick app*" to measure it, you definitely don't know about it. :) The "*few microseconds*" you may measure with a microbenchmark is not the full story. Please make a non-trivial app where cache/memory pressure matters and you will see the difference.

Comment: @ChefGladiator C has nothing to do with this and is no different; I am not sure what you are talking about. As for "*inventing requirements*", well... if time/space requirements are not your requirements, why are you using something like C++ to begin with? There far more productive languages when you can relax the constraints.

Comment: OP had a simple question, I answered change has no benefit, then you answered it has... please take the way you have chosen.

Comment: @ChefGladiator `unique_ptr` has some objective advantages that I pointed out and you claimed they aren't worth/measurable. I am not sure what is bad about discussing it. In any case, if you are the one that downvoted, please explain why you did so. The answer is fairly thorough.

Comment: @ChefGladiator By the way, `std::optional` does *not* require TriviallyDestructible, just Destructible.